# Send html form data to sql database via php (using mysqli)

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

I want to send the data inputted into an html form to my sql database, i.e., create a new row attributing certain values to certain columns. I know there are similar questions, I read the answers but nothing seems to work.

send_post.php

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("my host","my user","my passwrod","my db");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (category, title, contents, tags)
VALUES ('$_POST[post_category]', '$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_contents]', '$_POST[post_tags]')";
?>
```

post.html#form

```
<form onSubmit="send_post.php" method="post">
    <h3>Category:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="post_category">
    <h3>Post title:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="post_title">
    <h3>Post tags (a,b,c...):</h3>
    <input type="text" name="post_tags">
    <h3>Post (use html):</h3>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="post_contents"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

my db "posts" table colums:

```
pid
title
contents
tags
category
```

`pid` has `auto_increment` on

I have already tried sending values to all colunes, including `pid`, and in the "right" order.

The `mysqli_connect` part isn't the issue since I copied it from a different .php file of mine that works.

Server php-sql compatibility isn't the issue either, since I successfully had a different .php file retrieve data from the db (data which was manually inserted).

Comment: When you say nothing seems to work, what isn't working? Are you getting an error, wrong data in the db, etc?

Comment: I meant none of the solutions provided by answers from different questions worked. I was getting no error output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

change this

```
<form onSubmit="send_post.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
```

Comment: That was it. I was so focused on the .php I'd never suspect of that. I don't understand why it'd make a difference, though. Thank you.

Comment: @user117893 onSubmit calls a javascript function when the submit button is pressed, the action of a form is the url page to submit the form to.

Comment: Oh alright. I was working with javascript before that, that's why I had onSubmit. Thank you, Eli.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("my host","my user","my password","my db");
```

Don't forget to correct all spelling mistakes, can be a hassle when you don't know what is going wrong. (misspelt password as password)